# After upgrading Spring version from 5.2.20.RELEASE to 5.3.18 Dispatcher responses with 404

Tags: spring

I just tried to upgrade my Spring MVC application fro 4.3 to 5.3 and ended with no page in the browser and no message in any log file. The runtime environment is java8 and tomcat9.
Changing the log4j2 config for org.springframework.web.servlet to get debug output I could see messages like these:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/app/intro.html", parameters={}
WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for GET /app/intro.html
```

After some investigation with other versions of the spring framework I found out that the application works latest with springframework version 5.2.20. Any change of the spring version to 5.3.x will result in the above messages. Now after some days searching around an reading hundreds of pages I have no idea anymore, where to have a look.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://JAVA.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>app</display-name>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <error-page> 
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error404.html</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

and my app-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
">
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.app" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:demo" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="cookieName" value="locale"/>
        <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="7200"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="applicationContextProvider" class="de.app.util.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="locale" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is the class for the intro page:

```
package de.app.controller;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CookieValue;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import de.app.util.ApplicationContextProvider;
@Controller
public class IntroController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/intro")
    public String intro(Model model, Locale locale,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpSession session,
            @CookieValue(value="session", defaultValue="") String sessionCookie) {

        return "intro";
    }
}
```

And here are the dependencies of the pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <org.webjars.bootstrap-version>4.5.3</org.webjars.bootstrap-version>
    <org.webjars.jquery-version>3.6.0</org.webjars.jquery-version>
    <org.webjars.popperjs-version>2.9.3</org.webjars.popperjs-version>
    <org.webjars.hammerjs-version>2.0.8</org.webjars.hammerjs-version>
    <org.webjars.font-awesome-version>5.15.1</org.webjars.font-awesome-version>
    <org.springframework-version>5.3.18</org.springframework-version>
    <org.springframework-security-version>5.6.2</org.springframework-security-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.36</org.slf4j-version>
    <org.quartz-version>2.3.2</org.quartz-version>
    <log4j2-version>2.17.2</log4j2-version>
    <owasp-java-html-sanitizer-version>20211018.2</owasp-java-html-sanitizer-version>
    <postgresql-version>42.3.3</postgresql-version>
    <mariadb-client-version>3.0.4</mariadb-client-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-security-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Commons Upload --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>19.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.210</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>${mariadb-client-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${org.quartz-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>${org.quartz-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
        <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
        <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>${org.webjars.bootstrap-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
        <version>${org.webjars.font-awesome-version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>${org.webjars.jquery-version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>popper.js</artifactId>
        <version>${org.webjars.popperjs-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>hammerjs</artifactId>
        <version>${org.webjars.hammerjs-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer</groupId>
        <artifactId>owasp-java-html-sanitizer</artifactId>
        <version>${owasp-java-html-sanitizer-version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with that setup?
If you need more information please let me know.

Many thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 1):

In web.xml , add a url pattern with /intro.do and in your controller class specify the request mapping as intro.do and it should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. That solved my problem. I'm wondering why all the examples I found never had an extension in the request mapping.